# Area Booking System By Date Query For Maximum Area Availability within Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to implement a simple area booking application by date

I record the booking requests

Total Area is constant: Assume 100sqft

Table:

req_made

startdate|enddate|area|storagename

Example:

```
    01 Aug|__________________________________100_avail________________________|31 Aug
                   06 Aug|____________________________50_____________|25 Aug
                  05 Aug|____40__________|11 Aug
                                             18 Aug|____30_______|23 Aug
                                     13 Aug|_10_|16 Aug
    My Request:                 08 Aug|#######################|20 Aug  

Answer=>Maximum possible within range 10
Area Free:   
          |-------100---||---10----------|-|-40-|50|-------20----|-50|--100--|
                        60                50
```

[Same Diagram in written format (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZyO.jpg)

My SQL Query Attempt:

```
SELECT (100-SUM(req_made.area)) AS area,req_made.storagename
 FROM req_made
 WHERE (req_made.enddate >= '2016-08-20' AND
       req_made.startdate <= '2016-08-20')
 OR(req_made.enddate>='2016-08-08' AND
    req_made.startdate<= '2016-08-08')
OR(req_made.enddate<='2016-08-20' AND
    req_made.startdate>= '2016-08-08')
 GROUP BY req_made.storagename
```

Result
-30|my_storage

Expected
10|my_storage

Comment: Event B can be said to overlap event A if event B starts before event A ends, and ends after Event A starts.

Comment: Great input. Can you help me from the query keeping that in mind? I'm still stuck.

Comment: Really? You can't even make a guess?

Comment: If 100 is booked from 1st to 31st, then surely there's no availability.

Comment: 100 is total available area. Let me clarify that.

Comment: I still don't get it. I think I don't understand the term 'max' in this context. 'Min' would make more sense to me !?!